# Replace CKAN plugin javascript position in HTML code

Tags: ckan

Can somebody tell me how to change javascript call position in CKAN plugin HTML code?

Currently custom plugin which I create puts javascript code before `</body>` tag at the end of HTML code.

I try to change source template and to put scripts block before start of `<body>` tag, but CKAN puts javascript at the end, as I say above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using fanstatic to include your resource, with the `{% resource %}` tag, then it will always be included along with the rest of the javascript resources at the bottom of the page.

An easy way to include it at the top of the page is to link it as a static file instead of a fanstatic resource.

Otherwise, you can figure out why you need it at the top instead of the bottom, and try to fix any dependencies instead.